# Oracle Look behind Positive

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

There is no example of look behind expression in [Oracle Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10795/adfns_re.htm#1007996), so i tried using Java syntax,
This my query that supposed to get any digit after `TOP`

```
select regexp_substr('TIPTOP4152','(?<=TOP)\d+') sub from dual
```

But nothing to be displayed !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the sake of argument, REGEXP_SUBSTR works too:

```
SQL> select regexp_substr('TIPTOP4152', 'TOP(\d+)', 1, 1, NULL, 1) nbr
    from dual;

NBR
----
4152

SQL>
```

Comment: Final parameter '1', fetches the first capturing group. [Oracle 11g docs on REGEXP_INSTR](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions136.htm#SQLRF06300): _If subexpr is zero, then the position of the entire substring that matches the pattern is returned. If subexpr is greater than zero, then the position of the substring fragment that corresponds to subexpression number subexpr in the matched substring is returned. If pattern does not have at least subexpr subexpressions, the function returns zero. A null subexpr value returns NULL. The default value for subexpr is zero._

Comment: ie, positive lookbehind doesnt seem to work in Oracle, use the "trick" in this solution with capturing groups instead.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure that Oracle supports lookbehind. Instead you should be able to do this pretty easily with `regexp_replace`

```
REGEXP_REPLACE('TIPTOP4152', '.*TOP(\d+)', '\1')
```

Comment: Good one, but it will give numbers and anything after numbers if exists, try `TIPTOP4152.csv` => `4152.csv`