# Regex to get everything between a dot and a space regexp_substr

Tags: oracle, regexp-substr

In an Oracle database I have a string such as `12.13 this is a test`. Using regexp_substr I'm trying to extract just `13`. That is the number after the dot and before the space. I've tried various combinations and `(string, '\.[0-9]{1,}')` comes closest but I still get `.13`. Is there any way to just return `13`?

The data also includes items like `1.1`. At most the numbers will go `99.99`.

All possible number formats are: `#.#`, `#.##`,`##.#`,`##.##`

Comment: Thanks RedRaven.  Do all the numbers have a decimal . or only some?

Comment: @alexgibbs: see edit for possible formats. All numbers have a decimal. I want everything after the decimal, but not the decimal.

Comment: @RedRaven from a pure Regex perspective you need a positive lookbehind, however, it doesn't appear that this functionality is supported in Oracle as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32359433/oracle-look-behind-positive)

Comment: Will there always be a space after the digits you need, or could the number (like 12.13 in your example) be at the end of the string, so there would be no space after 13?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the input strings will always have leading numbers and a dot, one can extract the fractional numbers with `regexp_substr`.  `regexp_replace` could also be used.

Here are a few examples for `regexp_substr`.  These work by including a capturing group targeting the desired data, and a `subexpression` argument (the last argument in `regexp_substr`):

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('12.13 this is a test','^[0-9]{1,}[.]{1}([0-9]{1,})',1,1,NULL,1) AS FRACTIONAL FROM DUAL;
```

Result:

```
FRACTIONAL
13

1 row selected.

SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('1.1 this is a test','^[0-9]{1,}[.]{1}([0-9]{1,})',1,1,NULL,1) AS FRACTIONAL FROM DUAL;
```

Result:

```
FRACTIONAL
1

1 row selected.

SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('99.99 this is a test','^[0-9]{1,}[.]{1}([0-9]{1,})',1,1,NULL,1) AS FRACTIONAL FROM DUAL;
```

Result:

```
FRACTIONAL
99

1 row selected.
```

Answer (score 1):

I like `regexp_replace` better than `regexp_substr` for such tasks.

```
regexp_replace(str, '^.*?\.([[:digit:]]+).*$', '\1');
```

i.e. look for the wohle string from the start, with some characters, a point, some digits, some characters until the end, but remember only the digits and return those instead of the string.

But I guess that's just a matter of personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

```
select regexp_substr('12.13 this is a test', '\d+\.(\S+)', 1, 1, null, 1) rs
from dual;

RS
--
13
```

Comment: Add some explanation to improve quality of your answer

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Oracle-Regular-Expression-Support.html#GUID-969230D6-FC1A-4C75-BF2A-6B1BE909DED6